# ARP : What Mac ARP does request when a Host want to communicate to Host in different Network

Tags: arp

Please Clarify my doubt in ARP. In the below Topology,.
Looking for better understanding, how ARP works when Hosts are connected between default Gateways .

Host A(10.10.10.1)-----Switch-----(10.10.10.2)Router(20.20.20.2)--------HostB

1. When a Host want to communicate to Host B , does hostA send an ARP request for Destination IP (20.20.20.1)  or to Default Gateway (10.10.10.2) .
2. If it send ARP for HOST B mean, Host A identifies Host B is in different network, it will send the Packet only to the Configured Default Gateway , so will it request for Default Gateway Mac address
3. Host B mac will not be learnt by Host A by any cost,  So does Host A will generate ARP request for each time?

Answer (score 1):

Since a MAC address is only useful for a layer-2 domain which is bounded by a layer-3 device (router), a host will not ARP for a MAC address on a different subnet unless it has a misconfigured mask.

The host will ARP for the address of its configured gateway so that it can send the frame to the gateway, and the gateway will remove the layer-2 frame and try to forward the layer-3 packet to the port toward the end host. The router will then encapsulate the layer-3 packet with a new layer-2 frame (possibly using ARP if the nest hop isn't in its ARP cache) for the next link.